# Finding a matching to connect subsets of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity

I'm studying a graph problem which, strangely, has applications in bioinformatics.
I'm not asking for a solution, but rather for advice as to whether 
something similar to what I do has been studied before.
Especially about the notion of connectedness not between 
vertices, but subsets of vertices.
Some of the concepts in here might already have names, but 
I couldn't find anything.

We're given a graph $G$ and a partition $I$ of $V(G)$ into 
(not necessarily maximal) independent sets.

The goal is to find a set of independent edges that "connect" $I$.
I don't know how to define it precisely, but we could say two parts
$X, Y \in I$ are connected if there exists a vertex in $X$ and another in $Y$ that share an edge.
And transitively, for some $X, Y, Z \in I$, if $X,Y$ are connected as well as $Y, Z$, 
then $X, Z$ are connected.  This is even if $G$ is not connected.
For instance, you could have $I=\{X,Y,Z\}$ with $X=\{x_1, x_2\}, Y=\{y_1, y_2\}, Z=\{z\}$, 
and if we have the edges $x_1y_1$ and $y_2z$, then we say $I$ is connected.

I guess it's some sort of definition of "connected" generalized to 
subsets of vertices.

OK, so the problem is given $G$ and $I$, does there exist a set of independent
edges $M$ (or a matching if you will), such that $I$ is connected
when $G$ is restricted to $M$ ?
And the ultimate question is to evaluate the complexity of this decision problem.

It is not too hard to make a reduction using the Hamiltonian path problem
to show that this is NP-Complete.

However, it happens that because of some real-life contraints, my graphs are cographs 
(i.e. they have no induced $P_4$).
It has been shown that we can solve the Hamiltonian path problem (and a few others)
in linear time for this class of graphs.
This makes NP-Hardness reductions much harder, and doesn't make the decision problem any easier either.

One last note, the real problem I'm trying to solve is not to find a matching, 
but a set of independent cliques that connect I (call it a clique matching I guess - is there a name for that ?).
But I start with the seemingly easier case of edge matching.